# Python Create dictionary if properties are found

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

I'm trying to build a dictionary from multiple lists. The problem is, if a given list if empty, then I dont want it included in the dict.

Heres the possible keys

```
   'required',
   'as_banner',
   'min',
   'chart_layout',
   'client_name',
   'filter_text',
   'sort_order',
   'chart_type',
   'chart_color',
   'position',
   'order'
```

heres my method of building the dict:

```
propertyDict = dict()
propertyDict["required"] = requiredtype
propertyDict["as_banner"] = as_bannertype
propertyDict["min"] = mintype
propertyDict["chart_layout"] = chart_layouttype
propertyDict["client_name"] = clientnametype
propertyDict["filter_text"] = filter_texttype
propertyDict["sort_order"] = sort_ordertype
propertyDict["chart_type"] = charttype
propertyDict["chart_color"] = chart_colortype
propertyDict["position"] = positiontype
propertyDict["order"] = ordertype
```

Heres my script in which I append the values of key if it exists in the "field" collection.

```
for table in mtd_tom.Tables:
    if not is_profile_table(table, type="mtd"):
        if table.Description == "Sport Parents (Regrouped)":
            for i, subaxis in enumerate(table.Axes['Side'].SubAxes):
                nField = shatter_sae(subaxis.Specification)['varName']
                field = mdd.Fields[nField]

                if field.Properties.Item['required']:
                    requiredtype.append(field.Properties.Item['required'])
                if field.Properties.Item['as_banner']:
                    as_bannertype.append(field.Properties.Item['as_banner'])
                if field.Properties.Item['min']:
                    mintype.append(field.Properties.Item['min'])
                if field.Properties.Item['chart_layout']:
                    chart_layouttype.append(field.Properties.Item['chart_layout'])
                if field.Properties.Item['client_name']:
                    clientnametype.append(field.Properties.Item['client_name'])
                if field.Properties.Item['filter_text']:
                    filter_texttype.append(field.Properties.Item['filter_text']) 
                if field.Properties.Item['sort_order']:
                    sort_ordertype.append(field.Properties.Item['sort_order'])   
                if field.Properties.Item['chart_type']:                
                    charttype.append(field.Properties.Item['chart_type'])
                if field.Properties.Item['chart_color']:
                    chart_colortype.append(field.Properties.Item['chart_color'])
                if field.Properties.Item['position']:
                    positiontype.append(field.Properties.Item['position'])
                if field.Properties.Item['order']:
                    ordertype.append(field.Properties.Item['order'])                        
                else:
                    print "%s not found" % properties[i]
```

Heres the output as it is for now:

```
{'as_banner': [], 'chart_color': ['green', 'pink', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow', 'white'], 'chart_layout': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], 'sort_order': ['asending', 'desending', 'asending', 'desending', 'asending', 'asending', 'asending', 'desending'], 'chart_type': ['bar', 'WeightedBar', 'column', 'pie', 'line', 'column', 'line', 'pie'], 'client_name': ['Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)'], 'filter_text': [], 'required': [], 'position': [], 'min': [], 'order': []}
```

Note, I dont want keys with empty values included...

And I dont want to create a copy of the list which excludes keys with empty values...

any suggested on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably easiest to just filter out empty lists after building your dictionary:

```
propertyDict = {k: v for k, v in propertyDict.iteritems() if v}
```

The alternative would be to build your dictionary in your loop, and only add a new key-value pair when adding to the list; a [`collections.defaultdict()` instance](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would make that much easier

```
from collections import defaultdict

propertyDict = defaultdict(list)
properties = ('required', 'as_banner', 'min', 'chart_layout', 'client_name',
              'filter_text', 'sort_order', 'chart_type', 'chart_color',
              'position', 'order')

for i, subaxis in enumerate(table.Axes['Side'].SubAxes):
    nField = shatter_sae(subaxis.Specification)['varName']
    field = mdd.Fields[nField]
    for prop in properties:
        value = field.Properties.Item[prop]
        if value:
            propertyDict[prop].append(value)

# optional, turn `defaultdict` back into a `dict` object. This step is really
# not needed unless you need the `defaultdict.__missing__` behaviour to cease for
# later code.
# propertyDict = dict(propertyDict)
```

This code is *vastly* simpler by using a list of property names to test for as well

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I dont want a copy of the dict.

Comment: @Boosted_d16: it is a shallow copy of the original dict you just built. It is as close to the same as you can get. Only the dict object itself is rebuild; the keys and values are *the exact same objects*.

Answer (score 2):

Filter out the empty keys using a dict-comprehension:

```
>>> d = {'as_banner': [], 'chart_color': ['green', 'pink', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow', 'white'], 'chart_layout': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], 'sort_order': ['asending', 'desending', 'asending', 'desending', 'asending', 'asending', 'asending', 'desending'], 'chart_type': ['bar', 'WeightedBar', 'column', 'pie', 'line', 'column', 'line', 'pie'], 'client_name': ['Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)'], 'filter_text': [], 'required': [], 'position': [], 'min': [], 'order': []}
>>> {k:v for k, v in d.iteritems() if v}
{'chart_layout': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], 'client_name': ['Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)'], 'chart_color': ['green', 'pink', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow', 'white'], 'sort_order': ['asending', 'desending', 'asending', 'desending', 'asending', 'asending', 'asending', 'desending'], 'chart_type': ['bar', 'WeightedBar', 'column', 'pie', 'line', 'column', 'line', 'pie']}
```

For Python2.6 and earlier use:

```
dict(((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if v))
```

To update the original dict itself use `del` on the keys with empty values:

```
>>> for k, v in d.items():
    if not v:
        del d[k]

>>> d
{'chart_layout': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], 'chart_color': ['green', 'pink', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow', 'white'], 'chart_type': ['bar', 'WeightedBar', 'column', 'pie', 'line', 'column', 'line', 'pie'], 'client_name': ['Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)'], 'sort_order': ['asending', 'desending', 'asending', 'desending', 'asending', 'asending', 'asending', 'desending']}
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I dont want a copy of the dict.

Comment: thanks for your time, didnt even know you can edit the actual dict itself but I was look for what Martjin did, create the dict in the loop. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Put your types in a list. Loop through the dict and the list. You're done!

```
types = [requiredtype, as_bannertype, ..]
for k, v in propertyDict.items():
    for t in types:
        if v:
            t.append(v)
```